# Only pass the first argument is enough when template member function has multiple arguments?

Tags: c++

I am reading `Mesos` code, and come across the following function call:

```
install<SlaveRegisteredMessage>(
  &Slave::registered,
  &SlaveRegisteredMessage::slave_id,
  &SlaveRegisteredMessage::connection);
```

and its corresponding template member function is:

```
template <typename T>
class ProtobufProcess : public process::Process<T>
{
    ......
    template <typename M,
              typename P1, typename P1C,
              typename P2, typename P2C>
    void install(
      void (T::*method)(const process::UPID&, P1C, P2C),
      P1 (M::*p1)() const,
      P2 (M::*p2)() const)
    {
        ......
    }
    ......
}
```

So, only passing the first argument is enough, no need to use the following format:

```
install<SlaveRegisteredMessage, SlaveID, SlaveID, MasterSlaveConnection, MasterSlaveConnection>(...);
```

Comment: Template type deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the template argument are deductible, so you don't need to specify those template argument.

So:

```
install(...);
```

is enough in most case.

if you have overload for one parameter as for

```
void (T::*method)(const process::UPID&, P1C, P2C)
```

You have to help compiler in some way:

- provide template argument (until all of those template parameters are provided)
- specify which overload to choose (`static_cast<void (T::*)(const process::UPID&, int, char)>(&T::foo)`).